# How to analyze scale-free signals and get signal properties

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, similarity

I am new with signal processing, i have following signals which i've got after some pre-processing on original signals.[image]
You can see some of them has some similarities with others and some doesn't. but the problem is They have various range(in this example from 1000 to 3000).

## Question

How can i analysis their properties scale-free(what i mean from properties is statistical properties of signals or whatever)??

> **Note that** i don't want to cross-comparing the signals, i just want independent signals signatures which i can run some process on them sometime later.

Anything would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a filter that separates signals that follow this pattern from signals that don't, well, there's tons of things you could do!

Just think practically. As a first shot at it, you could do something like this (in this order):

1. Check if the signals are all-positive
2. Check if the first element is close in value to the last element
3. Check if the maximum lies "in the middle" somewhere
4. Check if the first value is small, then the signal grows, then shrinks again
5. Check if the growth rates are gradual. You could for example analyze their derivatives (after smoothing):

   a. derivative should be all-positive for a while, then all-negative.

   b. derivative should be smooth (no jumps greater than some tolerance)

Without additional knowledge about the signal's nature/origin, it's going to be hard to come up with more meaningful metrics than these...

Comment: Thanks for answering, To answering to "What are the signal's origin?": The signal's origin is a 2D map of images' edges,The signals are passed throw several filters/mappers, They are converted from 2D into 1D with 2 different mapping technique, then one of the maps is convoluted with other's hyperboliced map. but the procedure you've proposed are not accurate enough, i need something more accurate.